# WPF- How to hide a dropdown menu after click

Tags: c#, wpf, drop-down-menu, split-button, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a `SplitButton` in my WPF window, which is borrowed from Xceed's Extended WPF Toolkit. Its dropdown content is consisted of some `RadioButton`s. Something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.Test3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        Title="Test3" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Height="25" Width="150">
        <tk:SplitButton Content="Default Command">
            <tk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
                <StackPanel>
                    <RadioButton Content="Default Command" GroupName="variations" Margin="5" IsChecked="True"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Alternate Command 1" GroupName="variations" Margin="5"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Alternate Command 2" GroupName="variations" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </tk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
        </tk:SplitButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

which generates something like this:

[image: test]

The problem is, when I click on each of the `RadioButton`s the dropdown menu doesn't dissappear. I did some googling and realized that I should handle the `Click` event for each `RadioButton`. But I don't know how to hide the dropdown menu in that event handler. As a side-note, it seems a `MenuItem` [has the property of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5260880/5358284) `StaysOpenOnClick`, but there is no such thing for other controls.

Although doing this programmatically would suffice, but is there an MVVM way for this?

Comment: Not exactly a solution for your problem, but why do you prefer radiobuttons over a dropdownlist?

Comment: @Zure what is a dropdownlist? the `SplitButton` has a `DropDownContent` property, which can either be filled with `MenuItem`s or something like the one I tried. I didn't get what you mean

Comment: sorry, what I meant is a ComboBox: https://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox-wpf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add Checked event on your radio  button  and use `SplitoButton.IsOpen=false;`. Follow this code.

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <tk:SplitButton Name="SplitButton" Content="Default Command">

            <tk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>

                <StackPanel>
                    <RadioButton Checked="rb_Checked" Content="Default Command" GroupName="variations" Margin="5" IsChecked="True"/>
                    <RadioButton Checked="rb_Checked" Content="Alternate Command 1" GroupName="variations" Margin="5"/>
                    <RadioButton Checked="rb_Checked" Content="Alternate Command 2" GroupName="variations" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </tk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
        </tk:SplitButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

.cs

```
 private void rb_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SplitButton.IsOpen = false;
        }
```